# Inserting DIVs from right with slick effects

Tags: javascript, animation, html, css-float

I was wondering how to make a script that pushes in Divs from the right of my screen.

These Divs are floating right, so when there are too many on one row they one that is longest on the row (one on the left) hops to the next row.

But I want a function that adds a div (just outside of the screen) and pushes it into the screen.

Any idea's ?

Comment: Pushes it in from the left or the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocked up a demo for you http://jsfiddle.net/rW5rC/3/

Allows you to add a new element on button click which starts invisible offscreen and slides in.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use jQuery, then you can prepend or append certain container

so if you want to insert div in one container at the start use

```
$('#id_of_container').prepend('<div class="left">my div</div>');
```

if you want to add it at the end

```
$('#id_of_container').append('<div class="left">my div</div>');
```

its much easier to manipulate html with the jQuery, and you don't have to change your code for different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `animate` method, it's very simple to do:

```
$("div").animate({
   left: 200
});
```

I made you a demo here:

http://jsbin.com/ububer